# C# Windows Forms добавить элемент

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

Пытаюсь сделать вывод данных из БД в следующем виде:

- Получаю массив объектов из БД
- Вывожу каждый объект в виде checkBox

Написал вот такой вот код для добавления checkBox на форму, но почему то добавляется только первый

```
CheckBox checkBox1 = new CheckBox();
checkBox1.Text = "Item 1";
checkBox1.AutoCheck = true;
Controls.Add(checkBox1);

CheckBox checkBox2 = new CheckBox();
checkBox2.Text = "Item 2";
checkBox2.AutoCheck = true;
Controls.Add(checkBox2);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём моя ошибка?

Вывод

[image: изображение]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.
Проблема заключалась в том, что при создании элементы по дефолту располагаются в левом верхнем углу, и один элемент находился поверх другого.

Для исправления ошибки нужно задать координаты второму элементу, пример ниже

```
CheckBox checkBox1 = new CheckBox();
checkBox1.Text = "Item 1";
checkBox1.AutoCheck = true;
Controls.Add(checkBox1);

CheckBox checkBox2 = new CheckBox();
checkBox2.Text = "Item 2";
checkBox2.AutoCheck = true;
Controls.Add(checkBox2);

checkBox2.Location = new Point(100, 100);
```

Comment: Либо использовать `FlowLayoutPanel`/`TableLayoutPanel`, познакомьтесь с ними.

Comment: Чем точнее поставишь вопрос, тем быстрее получишь ответ. Не "почему-то добавляется только первый", а "почему-то я вижу только первый" (или второй?), или точнее "почему-то я вижу только один". А как понять, что второй не добавляется? Ошибка же не происходит, весь код выполняется.